# angularJS variable not changed in then for promise

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I initialized an array and got the data through a function call that returns a promise. In the `then` I populated the array and printing the array works fine. Outside of the promise I try to access the array and it's back to being empty. How can I keep the changes made in the `then` function?

```
var arr : IHash = {};
this.getTags(parameters)
    .then((data) => {
         for (var t in data.Tags) {
             arr[t] = data.Tags[t];
             this.$log.debug(arr["firstindex"]); //outputs data
         }
         }, (err) => {
             this.$log.debug(err);
         });

        this.$log.debug(arr["firstindex"]); //prints nothing
```

Comment: Your first log statement prints after your second log statement. That should tell you what's going on, this is asynchronous code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Promise is asynchronous, so `this.$log.debug(arr["firstindex"]);` is getting called before the array is populated.

Comment: I just realized this as I posted it. That was embarrassing thanks!